# Transfer timeout in UTL_SMTP with specific sender domain

Tags: oracle, email, oracle11g, smtp

When I attempt to email myself using oracles UTL_SMTP package, I am getting a transfer timeout error (ORA-29276) from the UTL_SMTP.MAIL procedure, but only when the sender variable is using a landmail.com domain. Other addresses work correctly, such as fake@email.com - but whatever@landmail.com does not.

I've tried retyping it out to ensure there were no wierd hidden characters or aything, but I am otherwise completely baffled, and my google-fu returns nothing.

It may be relevant that we recently updated from 10g to 11g.

The code prior to the timeout is pretty straight forward - it looks like the following, where checkpoint C is never reached...

```
PROCEDURE send_email(sender_email_chr IN VARCHAR2
                    ,other_stuff      IN WHATEVER)
IS
  connection_col UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
  reply_col      UTL_SMTP.REPLY;
BEGIN
  reply_col := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION('localhost',25,connection_col,60);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checkpoint A');

  reply_col := UTL_SMTP.HELO(connection_col,'localhost');

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checkpoint B');

  UTL_SMTP.MAIL(connection_col, sender_email_chr);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checkpoint C');

  --rest of procedure snipped
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm it's strange. I think this has nothing to do with Oracle but with our local SMTP(sendmail, postfix) configuration (or DNS setup). Your local SMTP probably tries to validate an email while receiving.

Try to do the same from Unix command line. Or directly using "telnet localhost 25" and you will see how long it take till the email will be accepted by SMTP.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, it seems you were correct and this wasnt Oracle related. Our client fixed it up on their side of things - Didn't get the full rundown, but it was possibly spam filter related.